# I'm having trouble using this command : vim ~/.zshrc

Tags: vim, zshrc

if you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PASH
```

can some tell me how to edit this part and how to save it please

Comment: Use any editor you like. I would put changes to `PATH` in `.zprofile`, though, not `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question. But there is a typo that you may want to fix. At the end it should be $PATH instead of $PASH

`export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

instead of

`export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PASH`

Comment: yes I want to fix this path via terminal but the problem is that I couldn't